# Jaxb Marshalling a Point variable

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, point

So I started using Jaxb to create an XML copy of the files I am using with my program.

I have had no issues after implementing into my code, until I recently added a new class to my main class.

It saves/loads fine with the class is blank/unused, but I get `StackOverflowErrors` when attempting to Marshall the class with some data. (In one scenario, it will marshall with no problems at all??)

The error message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.quickCheckMemberAccess(Reflection.java:84)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:388)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.get(Accessor.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
```

The `.xml` file that outputs looks normal until it hits the new class i've added which is where it goes bad.

```
<positionPercentage>
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                        <location>
                            <x>0</x>
                            <y>0</y>
                            <location>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<location>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <location>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <location>
            <x>0</x>
            <y>0</y>
            <location>
                <x>0</x>
                <y>0</y>
                <location>
                    <x>0</x>
                    <y>0</y>
                    <location>
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                        <location>
                            <x>0</x>
                            <y>0</y>
                            <location>
```

Normally the xml for the `ws` class would look like this. It contains a `Map<String, WidgetLink> WidgetLinks`. This maps a keystring to a `WidgetLink`. The `WidgetLink` class contains a `WidgetCode`, `Point positionPercentage` and two strings. The point variable seems to be the problem of the program

```
<ws>
        <widgetLinks>
            <entry>
                <key>Main-Comp Rack Fault `%rackname`</key>
                <value>
                    <widgetCode>
                        <widgetName>LED-Circle-25x25</widgetName>
                        <variables>
                            <entry>
                                <key>`%XPOS%`</key>
                                <value></value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>`%YPOS%`</key>
                                <value></value>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>`%IO_ID%`</key>
                                <value></value>
                            </entry>
                        </variables>
                        <fullWidgetText> ALOT OF CODE CUT OUT BUT IT PRINTS FINE</fullWidgetText>
                        <filePath>LED-Circle-25x25.txt</filePath>
                    </widgetCode>
                    <positionPercentage>
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </positionPercentage>
                    <variableName>Comp Rack Fault `%rackname`</variableName>
                    <panelName>Main</panelName>
               </widgetLinks>
           </ws>
```

I have no idea what the `<location>` item would be, or where it is coming from?

All my classes use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` and my main class `Store` uses the code `@XmlRootElement(name = "Store")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

Is the error something to do with the `Point` variable?

Edit - I made the `Point` variable static so it wouldnt be written with the current settings of `XmlAccessType.FIELD` and it writes out fine. How can i Marshall a point variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i found a page that explains why a Point variable causes these infinite loop errors -> `StackOverflowError`

> Sometimes the best way to handle an unmappable class is to write a
>   "stand-in" class which can be mapped with JAXB, and convert between
>   the two classes in the XmlAdapter. In this example, we want to use the
>   Point class. Because of that class' getLocation() method (which JAXB
>   will pickup automatically and map), an infinite loop will occur during
>   marshalling. Because we cannot change the Point class, we will write a
>   new class, MyPoint, and use it in the adapter. - See more at:
>   http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm#sthash.A8OXPKIV.dpuf